# testing for ionic-cordova- not working in browser

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to Ionic. Ionic uses cordova plugins for implementing different functionalities. If there are no cordova plugin dependencies, then we can view output in browser and view the errors in browser console. If cordova plugins are used, then browser does not support the native plugins and it is not possible to test for errors in browser. Is there any best tool for debugging and testing for errors for these kind of projects. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about testing your app in an emulator like the [Android emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html)?

Comment: we can just test. I there is any error in code we are not able to identify (like console in browser).

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to test on real devices or at least emulators. Nothing replaces a real device. 
But if you want to test in the browser and you have plugins that you want to be loaded you can add the browser platform.

> ionic platform add browser
>
> ionic run browser

This is different from 'ionic serve'

Comment: Thank You,
I used the above commands. But it does not not open in browser. It shows

listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:8000 

in the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using cordova add sudo ionic cordova run browser, if you'd like to run it in your browser. And use `sudo ionic cordova run browser --livereload` which would apply updates while you are making changes to the application. Though, typically it's not good practice to apply sudo, as module dependency lack privileges to install sub-dependencies, which can later become troublesome if there are package updates. Hope that helps.

Comment: You can format the code segments of your post by adding backticks around them.

Comment: Thanks @GrantMiller